# Full Name regex validation

Tags: ruby, regex, validation

I have following test case for my validators:

```
context 'Validation successful' do
  specify :full_name do
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Full Name'                          ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Ka El'                              ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'José Manuel Barroso'                ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Janusz Korwin-Mikke'                ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Jean-Claude Van Damme'              ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Ms. Jan Levinson-Gould'             ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Robert Downey, Jr.'                 ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, "Joanna d'Arc"                       ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr.'        ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, "Brett d'Arras-d'Haudracey"          ))
    expect(validator.(:full_name, 'prof. dr hab. n. med. Szymon Dragan'))
  end
end
```

and:

```
context 'Validation failure' do
  specify :full_name do
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'Full  Name') }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'Full N4m3' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'Full N@me' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'FULL NAME' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'FuLl NaMe' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'Full NamE' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'K L'       ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'full name' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'Full name' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'full Name' ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, 'FullName'  ) }.to raise_error
    expect { validator.(:full_name, ''          ) }.to raise_error
  end
end
```

I can't find any regex that will satisfy my *full names*. I also tried to split names by special characters and then verify each element, but this leads me to not validate spaces between groups and so on.

```
def name_valid?(name)
  name.match /\A[^0-9~`!@#$%\^&*+_={}?()\[\];:<>]+\Z/
end
```

Any ideas how to deal with full name validation?

Comment: I just leave [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) here... ;-)

Comment: Who are you to say what a name can be? People are legally called things like "Prince" and "Sting".